# XmlPullParser from ftp with username and password

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, ftp, xmlpullparser

im using XmlPullParser and it works great. Now to the problem, i need to read an xml file on a ftp server on my web hotel. I have try to use the username and password in the url but it dosent seems to work on my web hotel, so is it a way to use username and password in this code?

```
URL urlXml;
try {
    urlXml = new URL(url);
    XmlPullParserFactory parserCreator = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser parser = parserCreator.newPullParser();
    parser.setInput(urlXml.openStream(), null);

    int parserEvent = parser.getEventType();
    while (parserEvent != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        parserEvent = parser.next();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it would be much easier to pull the file from FTP first and only then feed it to the XML parser, because there are quite a few things that may go wrong during the download, and handling them within the parser would be quite difficult.

Also, you should check if your URL contains user name/password in the proper format:
"ftp://user:password@server.com/file.dat" or something like that.

Comment: thanks for the reply, your solution sound good. the only thing I wonder about is if there are any barriers to consider when it comes to pulling files to android devices?

Comment: no barriers. it's a mobile platform. memory is (relatively) scarce, battery and cpu should be conserved as much as possible and the internet connection is kind of slow(ish) and prone to interruptions. if your file is relatively large (over 30sec at the current connection speed) it's usually a good idea to download it first, and then parse, so your parser does not choke when connection drops.